CMake cannot find Boost libraries in compiled-from-source Boost folder even though Boost_DEBUG output shows correct path
I have successfully built boost with emscripten using the following commands
git clone --recursive https://github.com/boostorg/boost.git --branch 1.85.0
cd boost
./bootstrap.sh
source ~/emsdk/emsdk_env.sh
./b2 toolset=emscripten --with-graph --with-filesystem --with-program_options

Now, I would like to have a CMake project use this local boost build. What I am doing is:
git clone https://.../cmakeproject.git cmakeproject
mkdir binaries
cd binaries
emcmake cmake -DBoost_DEBUG=1 -DBOOST_ROOT=/home/andy/boost ../cmakeproject

I unfortunately get the following error:
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1673 ] _boost_TEST_VERSIONS = "1.77.0;1.77;...;1.33.0;1.33"
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1674 ] Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED = "TRUE"
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1675 ] Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS = <unset>
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1676 ] Boost_USE_STATIC_RUNTIME = <unset>
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1677 ] Boost_ADDITIONAL_VERSIONS = <unset>
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1678 ] Boost_NO_SYSTEM_PATHS = <unset>
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1710 ] BOOST_ROOT = "/home/andy/boost"
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1711 ] ENV{BOOST_ROOT} = <unset>
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1712 ] BOOST_INCLUDEDIR = <unset>
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1713 ] ENV{BOOST_INCLUDEDIR} = <unset>
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1714 ] BOOST_LIBRARYDIR = <unset>
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1715 ] ENV{BOOST_LIBRARYDIR} = <unset>
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1787 ] _boost_INCLUDE_SEARCH_DIRS = "/home/andy/boost/include;/home/andy/boost;PATHS;C:/boost/include;C:/boost;/sw/local/include"
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1788 ] _boost_PATH_SUFFIXES = "boost-1_77_0;boost_1_77_0;...;boost/boost-1_33;boost/boost_1_33"
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1873 ] Boost_LIB_PREFIX = ""
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1874 ] Boost_NAMESPACE = "boost"
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:953 ] _boost_COMPILER = "-clang190" (guessed)
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1910 ] _boost_MULTITHREADED = "-mt"
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1988 ] _boost_ARCHITECTURE_TAG = "" (detected)
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1992 ] _boost_RELEASE_ABI_TAG = "-"
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1993 ] _boost_DEBUG_ABI_TAG = "-d"
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2053 ] _boost_LIBRARY_SEARCH_DIRS_RELEASE = "/home/andy/boost/lib;/home/andy/boost/stage/lib;Boost_INCLUDE_DIR-NOTFOUND/lib;Boost_INCLUDE_DIR-NOTFOUND/../lib;Boost_INCLUDE_DIR-NOTFOUND/stage/lib;PATHS;C:/boost/lib;C:/boost;/sw/local/lib"
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2054 ] _boost_LIBRARY_SEARCH_DIRS_DEBUG = "/home/andy/boost/lib;/home/andy/boost/stage/lib;Boost_INCLUDE_DIR-NOTFOUND/lib;Boost_INCLUDE_DIR-NOTFOUND/../lib;Boost_INCLUDE_DIR-NOTFOUND/stage/lib;PATHS;C:/boost/lib;C:/boost;/sw/local/lib"
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2239 ] Searching for FILESYSTEM_LIBRARY_RELEASE: boost_filesystem-clang190-mt-;boost_filesystem-clang190-mt;boost_filesystem-clang190-mt;boost_filesystem-mt-;boost_filesystem-mt;boost_filesystem-mt;boost_filesystem-mt;boost_filesystem
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2294 ] Searching for FILESYSTEM_LIBRARY_DEBUG: boost_filesystem-clang190-mt-d-;boost_filesystem-clang190-mt-d;boost_filesystem-clang190-mt-d;boost_filesystem-mt-d-;boost_filesystem-mt-d;boost_filesystem-mt-d;boost_filesystem-mt;boost_filesystem
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2239 ] Searching for GRAPH_LIBRARY_RELEASE: boost_graph-clang190-mt-;boost_graph-clang190-mt;boost_graph-clang190-mt;boost_graph-mt-;boost_graph-mt;boost_graph-mt;boost_graph-mt;boost_graph
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2294 ] Searching for GRAPH_LIBRARY_DEBUG: boost_graph-clang190-mt-d-;boost_graph-clang190-mt-d;boost_graph-clang190-mt-d;boost_graph-mt-d-;boost_graph-mt-d;boost_graph-mt-d;boost_graph-mt;boost_graph
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2239 ] Searching for PROGRAM_OPTIONS_LIBRARY_RELEASE: boost_program_options-clang190-mt-;boost_program_options-clang190-mt;boost_program_options-clang190-mt;boost_program_options-mt-;boost_program_options-mt;boost_program_options-mt;boost_program_options-mt;boost_program_options
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2294 ] Searching for PROGRAM_OPTIONS_LIBRARY_DEBUG: boost_program_options-clang190-mt-d-;boost_program_options-clang190-mt-d;boost_program_options-clang190-mt-d;boost_program_options-mt-d-;boost_program_options-mt-d;boost_program_options-mt-d;boost_program_options-mt;boost_program_options
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2239 ] Searching for SYSTEM_LIBRARY_RELEASE: boost_system-clang190-mt-;boost_system-clang190-mt;boost_system-clang190-mt;boost_system-mt-;boost_system-mt;boost_system-mt;boost_system-mt;boost_system
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2294 ] Searching for SYSTEM_LIBRARY_DEBUG: boost_system-clang190-mt-d-;boost_system-clang190-mt-d;boost_system-clang190-mt-d;boost_system-mt-d-;boost_system-mt-d;boost_system-mt-d;boost_system-mt;boost_system
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:230 (message):
  Could NOT find Boost (missing: filesystem graph program_options system)
  (found version "1.85.0")
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:594 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  /usr/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2360 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
  cmake/FindDependencies.cmake:7 (find_package)
  CMakeLists.txt:99 (include)

It seems that the build process cannot see my built libraries. _boost_LIBRARY_SEARCH_DIRS_RELEASE and _boost_LIBRARY_SEARCH_DIRS_DEBUG above both have /home/andy/boost/stage/lib in the library search path.
$ ls /home/andy/boost/stage/lib
cmake               libboost_atomic.so.1.85.0  libboost_filesystem.so.1.85.0  libboost_graph.so.1.85.0     libboost_program_options.so.1.85.0  libboost_regex.so.1.85.0  libboost_system.so.1.85.0
libboost_atomic.a   libboost_filesystem.a      libboost_graph.a               libboost_program_options.a   libboost_regex.a                    libboost_system.a
libboost_atomic.so  libboost_filesystem.so     libboost_graph.so              libboost_program_options.so  libboost_regex.so                   libboost_system.so

The build process does detect that I have version 1.85.0 built, suggesting the include directory is correctly read (and version.hpp correctly parsed, I guess).
I'm building from WSL using an Ubuntu 22.04 distribution. To be on the safe side, I tried the build from two different machines, from scratch (new Ubuntu WSL distribution) and always obtain the same result.

What project are you compiling? The CMake makes a difference. Does it use the CMake modules or "old-fashioned" FindPackage substitution-variables?

From what I understand, when run with emcmake, CMake has some fishy behavior: https://github.com/emscripten-core/emscripten/issues/19243#issuecomment-2052322085. This might be a bug.

I cannot see what your CMakeLists looks like, but I've been able to make my previous demo into a CMake project like so
Building Boost
Identical to the earlier demo but without --with-graph, so it builds all libraries enabled by default:
git clone --recursive https://github.com/boostorg/boost.git --branch boost-1.85.0 --depth=1 emboost --jobs=16
cd emboost
./bootstrap.sh
./b2 toolset=emscripten # --with-graph

The environment
I don't use emcmake, I prefer to let CMake figure it out by default:

File CMakeLists.txt
 cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)
 project(test_build)

 set(CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS On)
 set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
 set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -Wall -Wextra -pedantic")
 set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -fwasm-exceptions")

 set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS On)
 find_package(Boost 1.85.0 REQUIRED COMPONENTS graph)

 add_executable(test_build.js main.cpp)
 target_link_libraries(test_build.js Boost::graph)



The options are all optional except for Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS and -fwasm-exceptions, which seemed required to make the link work.
With the demo program unchanged:

File main.cpp
 #include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
 #include <boost/graph/graph_utility.hpp>
 #include <boost/graph/graphviz.hpp>

 struct Vertex {
   int id;
 };

 using G = boost::adjacency_list<boost::vecS, boost::vecS, boost::directedS, Vertex>;

 int main() {
     G g;
     boost::dynamic_properties dp;
     dp.property("node_id", get(&Vertex::id, g));

     std::istringstream dot(R"(digraph G {
         0;
         1;
         2;
         0 -> 1;
         1 -> 2;
         2 -> 0;
     })");

     read_graphviz(dot, g, dp);

     print_graph(g, get(&Vertex::id, g));
 }



We have the live demo:
export CXX=em++
export CC=emcc
export Boost_DIR=$PWD/../emboost/stage/lib/cmake 
cmake -B build .
make -C build/
node ./build/test_build.js 

Printing
0 --> 1 
1 --> 2 
2 --> 0 

Proving that the link was used because read_graphviz_new.cpp is a library object.


Could you please clarify what you mean by "I don't use emcmake, I prefer to let CMake figure it out by default"? I use emcmake, but don't mind using your emcmake-less approach - if I can understand it.

I cannot explain better than what I did, with the exact statements used. It's all there.

You mean emcmake just automatically adds the required CMAKE options (at the beginning of your CMakeLists.txt)? I believe this is what it does - if so, I take it. Thank you.

I don't know what emcmake does. I know what is required, and that's what I show in the answer. I imagine the most important thing is setting CXX and CC before CMake configures your project. (Note I even pointed out which options matter, and which are just me imagining a sane CMake project because you didn't provide one :))

Correct ;) I truly appreciate your effort.

In your answer, I don't seed where you instruct your CMakeLists.txt to use your boost build. How does your CMakeLists.txt know your boost build is in 'emboost'? EDIT: I see, that's the environment variable. And that's Boost_DIR, and not BOOST_ROOT. Gosh, I wish there were less variables with boost !

Not so much boost but rather CMake modules at fault there. And the fact that it keeps changing. Actually you're seeing the signs of progress (CMake support right in the boost release!) however I feel your pain: is annoying to run into brick walls every time it changes. I only barely know the basics to get by, which is why I try to stick to the bare minimum so I can cope :wry-smile:
